# Determining subgroup using closure

Tags: group-theory

I've made a stupid mistake somewhere, but I can't find it. Maybe I'm misunderstanding something.

[image]

Work so far:

Let **A, B** $\in \mathbb{R^*}$

$$A=
\begin{pmatrix}
r & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
r-s & 0 & s \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

and

$$B = 
\begin{pmatrix}
t & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
t-u & 0 & t \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

$$AB = 
\begin{pmatrix}
rt & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
rt-su & 0 & st \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

The matrix is of the form:
$$\begin{pmatrix}
a & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
a-b & 0 & b \\
\end{pmatrix}$$

with $a=rt$ and $b=su$. Also, $rt \in \mathbb{R^*}$ since $r, t \in \mathbb{R^*}$

But! This is where it doesn't make sense to me:

I want $rt-su \in \mathbb{R^*}$

But instead I have:

$rt-su \notin \mathbb{R^*}$ because, we can demonstrate:

Let $r=3, t=4, s=2, u=6$, then $rt-su=0 \notin \mathbb{R^*}$

But, it is assumed closure is satisfied. So where am I going wrong?

Comment: Why do you want $rt - su \in \Bbb{R}^*$? The definition of $H$ does not require this.

Comment: Please do not use images to convey important information about your query that is not present elsewhere in your post. [See here for reasons why this is bad practice](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/34123/742).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of $H$ does not require the $(3,1)$-entry to be nonzero: it only requires the $(1,1)$ and $(3,3)$ entries to be nonzero. The identity matrix lies in $H$ (with $a=b=1$), but it has $(3,1)$-entry equal to $0$; as does any matrix with $a=b\neq 0$.

Comment: I understand how you got that, but why are you multiplying the $(3,1)$-entries of A and B? It's a matrix multiplication, without simplification, it's:

$rt-ts+ts-su$

https://www.symbolab.com/solver/matrix-multiply-calculator/%5Cbegin%7Bpmatrix%7Dr%260%260%5C%5C%200%261%260%5C%5C%20r-s%260%26s%5Cend%7Bpmatrix%7D%5Cbegin%7Bpmatrix%7Dt%260%260%5C%5C%200%261%260%5C%5C%20t-u%260%26u%5Cend%7Bpmatrix%7D?or=input

Comment: @KAYoung: Because I find it hard to multiply matrices that are aligned vertically instead of horizontally in my head.

Comment: so my arithmetic was correct, it was just my assumption that $(3,1)$-entry must $\in \mathbb{R^*}$ which was incorrect?

Comment: Yes, your algebra was correct (mine wasn't before the edit). The definition of $H$ only requires $a$ and $b$ to be nonzero; it says nothing about $a-b$.  Not sure why you assumed that entry had to be nonzero.